# assigning output to a variable using echo command

Tags: shell

The below code does not give any output:

```
$echo `cat time`
19991213100942
$a=$(echo `cat time`) | echo $a | echo ${a:0:4}
```

Please tell where I am making mistake.

Comment: Pipes involve sub-shells. The pipe there is also useless and incorrect. Drop the pipe.

Comment: @user2610 please explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: @chaos : i want to store the output of echo to a variable and then segregate that string into different substrings.

Comment: @EtanReisner:I want to store the variable to "a" and use it further in my command line as shown.

Comment: What's wrong with simply `cat time`? Why do you have to capture the output of `cat` just to `echo` it again? Also, `echo` is not likely to read from stdin, so `... | echo ...` is a bit pointless.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=$(echo `cat time`)
```

assigns the output of the command inside the brackets `$(...)` to the variable `$a`.
Later in the script, you can print the variable:

```
echo $a
```

That prints: `19991213100942`

```
echo ${a:0:4}
```

That prints: `1999`

You can reference the varibale by its name `$a`.

Comment: I want to know why the command line is not working as a whole:        a=$(echo `cat time`) | echo $a | echo ${a:0:4}. It does not give any output.

Comment: You have to use semicolons, bot pipes: `a=$(echo cat time); echo $a; echo ${a:0:4}`

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to `echo` the output of `cat time`: just `cat time`.

Second, as @Etan says (kind of), replace the pipes with semicolons or newlines

```
a=$(< time)    # a bash builtin, equivalent to but faster than: a=$(cat time)
echo $a
echo ${a:0:4}
```